# Do I need extra software on the EV3 to use Robotary?

Tags: mindstorms

Do we need to install extra software on the EV3 or does Robotary (https://robotaryapp.com/) install programs just like the default LEGO Software.

Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the developers and no, you do not need external software, but your mac has to be running for the software to work on the EV3. They are connected via bluetooth or USB.

Comment: As an after comment, the app is good, but it occasionally crashes and it lacks a few functions of the mindstorm, but it is worthwhile.